# Adding length of values of a column of a dataframe when each value is a list

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this.

```
userID      upvotes 
abc1998     [abc1298]   
abc1998     [abc0369,abc9999]   
abc1998     []  
abc1998     []  
abc1998     []  
abc1998     [abc1991, abc1235]  
abc1998     [abc1992]
```

I want to add the length of the list of each column of the row 'upvotes' and store it in a variable i.e, the output should be `sum = 1+2+0+0+0+2+1 = 6`

Any help on this please?

Comment: `df.upvotes.str.len().sum()`

Answer (score 0):

`df.upvotes.str.len().sum()` This worked! Thanks @yatu